# Limit of the two variable function $f(x,y).$

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{4}+y^{2})}=0$$ I tried with different paths as $x=0,y=0, y=x$ its comes to zero but i have no general idea. Please help. Thanks to lot.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^4+y^2)} = x\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\left(\frac{y^2}{x^4+y^2}\right)$. Now each of terms in parentheses is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{4}+y^{2})}\right|
&=\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{4}+y^{2})}
\leq
\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\,(y^{2})}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}}=|x|\\ \ \\
&\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
\end{align}